# jprogressbar in swing

Tags: swing

Hi. I'm preparing a form in java where I want to show a progress bar from value 1 to 5 in an interval of 0.5 seconds each, but, in my code, the progress bar jumps directly from 1 to 5 after 2.5 secs ..
Please help me with the code...

```
    public class cafee extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JProgressBar pr1;
JButton b1;

public cafee() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pr1 = new JProgressBar();
    pr1.setSize(10, 1);

    pr1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    pr1.setMinimum(0);
    pr1.setMaximum(5);
    pr1.setValue(0);
    pr1.setVisible(true);
    b1 = new JButton();
    b1.setVisible(true);

    add(pr1);
    add(b1);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
        for (int a = 1; a <= 5; a++) {

            try {
                                     pr1.setValue(a);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    cafee caf = new cafee();
    caf.setVisible(true);
    caf.setSize(500, 500);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you sleep in the event dispatch thread (EDT), you're blocking it, and thus preventing all the other event handling and painting methods to occur. `JProgressBar` is useful to display the progress of some task running in a separate background thread.

Use a `SwingWorker`. Its api doc contains an easy to understand example.

Comment: Indeed, SwingWorker is the way to go. Read up on EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) and SwingWorker, and especially its publish() method will will let you "talk" with the EDT from the background thread.